# Configure Event Logger to log all or specific WPF events into specific log source and journal

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, filtering

I want to enable very noisy verbose WFP even for network packet audits. There will be a LOT of events and I'm curious if there is a way:

1. Specify a completely separate journal for them (not just filter)
2. Specify a separate log file source (so it wont pollute default)

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, there is **no way to change the destination log** of a specific set of events on a Windows system (moreover for the Security event log). However, the question you submit is raising another problem: how are you going to handle/browse/correlate all those events from all your Windows systems ? Because this would be the job of a SIEM ...

What I can advise or suggest :

- Create a custom view in the Event Viewer in order to easily access those events
- Create a GPO to change default log size and increase log retention
- use the Windows Event Forwarding (WEF) feature together with a Windows Event Collector (WEC) server based on the Palantir approach in order to collect ONLY the events you have mentionned. Once the events are collected on the WEC server, you can forward it to any SIEM you want.https://github.com/palantir/windows-event-forwarding

Comment: I'm looking at something like LiveTCPUPDWatch by Nirsoft and from what I father he essentially manages somehow to enable WFP packet audit and catch it inside his own context, separately from global windows logging context, essentially making its own logger. What I dont know is HOW he managed to did it, but that proves it is doable.

Comment: I personnaly don't know LiveTcpUdpWatch, but from what I see it does something more advance than the built-in "Resource Monitor". I suggest

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a new event log with the [New-EventLog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet:

```perl
New-EventLog -source TestApp -LogName TestLog -MessageResourceFile C:\Test\TestApp.dll
```

> [...]The operating system stores event logs as files.
>
> When you create a new event log, the associated file is stored in the $env:SystemRoot\System32\Config directory on the specified computer.
> [...]

Comment: Hmm, Not sure this has much relevance to my question. I dont need to register custom app, I need to redirect existing Audit events. Also. New-Eventlog only for to Windows prior Vista, since starting from Vista there is new event  system introduced.

Comment: I personnally don't know LiveTcpUdpWatch, but from what I see is totally independant from the WPF. I mean you can have it fully disable and still watch the established connections. Also, it seems pretty similar to the built-in "Windows Resource Monitor".

So not sure which direction you want to go. At any case you also have a look on the "Fibratus tool", which could somehow help: https://www.fibratus.io/#/kevents/network